# Cache in multi-tenant environment

Tags: caching, multi-tenant

I am developing a service that will host multiple tenants. The service will have a limited size cache that will be used by multiple tenants. I do not want to limit the cache size for individual tenants because then we are not effectively using the entire cache pool. But, not having a limit for individual clients might lead to abusing the cache (for example, one tenant may continuously cache the data that will never be retrieved again). What is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, a lot of factors come into picture for this use case. I guess you are using some sorta paid cache model like redis.

A question is how can you restrict size if tenants are not known beforehand. IFA tenant adds up on the fly,you cannot shrink the size of the cache already allowed to the existing tenants
Ideally the cache can be identified based on tenant ID the key. So when you add something to the cache for a tenant, you increase the usage amount on each store.

It would be better to bill the tenant based on the metered cache usage or use a customLRU algorithm to evict the unused cache.

Hope this helps.